# Change individual series color

Tags: reporting-services, charts, bar-chart, series

[image]

Hi,

I want to replicate the series color as above where an individual bar is shown in a specific color. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Series Properties** (right-click on the bar or click on the Values' value field down arrow  and Series Properties)

Click on the FILL tab.

Click on the Function (***fx***) button to enter an **expression**.

If it's a separate Value set, you can just change the color.

[image]

If all your chart data is in one value set, you can enter an expression like:

```
=IIF(Fields!YourField.Value = "Materials", "Plum", "Blue")
```

I'm guessing you use two separate sets of values - one for the dates and the other for Materials.